# Drop the condition μ(∅) = 0 in the definition of a measure. What changes?

Tags: measure-theory

Define a measure without the requirement μ(∅) = 0
as a non-negative $\sigma$-additive function on a $\sigma$-algebra. What changes?

This would (edit: only, see answers) further include the following object: the set function $\mu_\infty$ which constantly equals $\infty$. What does this entail for existence and uniqueness of measures, any theorems that become unwieldy by this convention? E.g. does dominated convergence still hold?

Comment: Well, you probably want $\mu(A\cup \emptyset)=\mu(A)$ so you'd have to weaken the assumption that $\mu$ is additive for disjoint sets.

Comment: @lulu I am happy if μ(∅) = 4 is excluded by disjoint additivity.

Comment: But you still have the problem that $\mu(A)=\mu(A)+\mu (\emptyset)$.  Blocking that will be difficult.

Comment: Do you have such a pseudo-measure in mind?  It's always easier to think of weakening (or otherwise altering) axiom systems if you have some clear example(s) in mind.  Something that sort of looks like what the axioms describes, and which is clearly interesting, but which doesn't quite mesh with the standard axioms.

Answer (score 6):

For nonnegative measures:
Of course $\mu(\varnothing) = \mu(\varnothing \cup \varnothing) = \mu(\varnothing)+\mu(\varnothing)$.  So either $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ or $\mu(\varnothing) = +\infty$.
Thus, if $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ fails, then we have $\mu(E) = \mu(E\cup\varnothing) = \mu(E) + \mu(\varnothing) = +\infty$ for all $E$.

---

The countable additivity axiom
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)\qquad\text{provided the sets } A_k \text{are pairwise disjoint}
\tag1$$
could be replaced by
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k \in K} A_k\right) = \sum_{k\in K} \mu(A_k)\qquad\text{provided the sets } A_k \text{are pairwise disjoint}
\tag2$$
where $K$ is a countable index set  (and "countable" allows finite, and even empty).  If $K = \varnothing$, then $\bigcup_{k \in K} A_k = \varnothing$ and $\sum_{k\in K} \mu(A_k) = 0$, so we recover $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ as a consequence of $(2)$.

Comment: That is very nice, this also makes it immediate that a σ-algebra is a special case of an algebra and gets around the awkward construction  A ∪ B = A ∪ B ∪ ∅ ∪ ∅ ∪ … to apply the series version of additivity

Comment: Let's be careful and use for (∅) =  ∑(∅) and not (∅) = (∅) + (∅)

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountableAdditivity.html wrongly suggests that (∅)=0 is needed to get finite additivity from countable additivity, but it's not immediate that finite additivity holds in this setting.